# Strtok Parsing and Storing into array

Tags: c, pointers, memcpy, strtok

I'm trying to parse some string which is to contain some filenames as arguments.
My objective is to **parse** a command and its parameters and **store** it to an 2d char array.

Example Input:

```
/* Where 'cmd' is a command, file* are the arguments */
cmd file1 file2 file3
```

Here is my code:

```
int8_t **file_names = NULL;

/* Allocate Memory for the array,  
Max of 5 files of max strlen 64 each */
file_names = malloc(sizeof(char *));
for(i=0; i<5; i++)
*(file_names + i) = malloc(sizeof(char) * 64);
```

---

```
/* Receive command from user */
cmd = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1024);
printf("Please Enter the command:\n");
fgets(cmd, 2048, stdin);
cmd[strlen(cmd) - 1] = '\0';   /* Overwrite Newline by '\0' char */
```

---

```
int j = 0;
/* Tokenise the file names and cpy to 2d array */
ptr = strtok(cmd, " ");        /* Contains command 'cmd' */
printf("First Token  : [%s]\n\n", ptr);

printf("Parsing Filenames now:\n");
while(ptr = (strtok(NULL, " ")))
{
    printf("\tToken  : [%s]\n", ptr));
    memcpy(*(file_names + j), ptr, strlen(ptr));        /* Copy to 2D array */
    printf("\tFile Name : [%s]\n", *(file_names + j));
    j++;
};
```

The Output is:

```
$ gcc 2d.c -Wall -Wextra
$ ./a.out 
Please Enter the command
cmd file1 file2 file3
First Token  : [cmd]

Parsing Filenames now
    Token  : [file1]
    File Name : [file1�,    ȡ,  �,  X�, ��, ]
    Token  : [file2]
    File Name : [file2]
    Token  : [file3]
    File Name : [file3]
```

**Issue**:

I don't know why first token is appended with junk.
While `ptr` gets correct data. I suspect `memcpy`, but `strlen` returns correct `5` bytes for `ptr`.

> **strtok(3)** also says:
>
> Each  call  to  strtok()  returns  a pointer to a null-terminated string containing the next token.

So I believe that it should null-terminated and should print `file1` only.

Comment: memcpying strlen doesn't include the terminator. honestly if you don't mind a posix solution you'd likely be better off just using `strdup` and throwing out that preallocation entirely. Even then you're asking for an overrun of the *pointer* array if more than five entries are provided.

Comment: That's right, A very careless mistake *Face-palm*. Thanks anyways!

Comment: What's the point of allocating a fixed-sized buffer beforehand when you can allocate when you know the sring length? (You also don't enforce your hard-coded limit.)

Comment: @WhozCraig, In that case, why only first token prints garbage and not the following tokens ? Yeah for now, i'm not handling the *overrun* condition

Comment: @SaurabhMeshram That would be the result of invoking *undefined behavior*. The code is wrong and the program ill-formed. You cannot assume behavior you *observe* is behavior that is *defined*. You can only draw that conclusion when your code is written with defined behavior and plays by the rules from the get-go.

Comment: this line: file_names = malloc(sizeof(char *)); should probably be: file_names = malloc(sizeof(char *)*5); to allow enough room for 5 pointers

Comment: this line: fgets(cmd, 2048, stdin); is allowing twice as many characters as is actually available from the prior malloc of only 1024 characters.  So a VERY long cmd would result in a overflow of the buffer pointed to by cmd.  Resulting in undefined behaviour and probably a seg fault event

Comment: this line: memcpy(*(file_names + j), ptr, strlen(ptr)); fails to copy the string terminator  so the printf goes until it happens to find a '\0' byte somewhere in memory (resulting in undefined behaviour and probable seg fault event)  suggest changing line to: memcpy(*(file_names + j), ptr, strlen(ptr)+1);